# Process still running from a deleted chroot?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, chroot

so I come to you with a somewhat interesting problem.

I had a chroot running that had an entire lamp server installed and running on it. I tried to purge and remove the lamp server but messed up somewhere so I figured if I just go back and remove the whole directory that contains the chroot which had the lamp running on it. When I did so I went back and created a new chroot and tried to just reinstall lamp on it I got an error while intalling mysql-server and so I looked and apache2 is still running however it does not show up on any services of any user I sign in with.

How do I completely remove my lamp even though it was deleted with the entire chroot and it's not in my files anywhere?

Best regards, JJ

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the process running, then just kill it.

Comment: No the problem is, it doesn't show that a process is running on any user. It's like it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Not sure how all of this happened.

Comment: You should edit your question. As it stands, it doesn't make much sense.